# Ping between two Linux systems via an intermediate Linux fails

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables, ping

I have a simple network with three Linux systems running CentOS 2.6.

```
       Linux 1
(eth1: 192.138.14.1/24)
          |
          |
(eth4: 192.138.14.4/24)
       Linux 2
(eth2: 192.138.4.3/24)
          |
          |
(eth3: 192.138.4.2/24)
       Linux 3
```

I am unable to ping Linux 3 from Linux 1. What I am able to ping though is from Linux 1 to Linux 2 (eth2) and from Linux 3 to Linux 2 (eth4). This means from Linux 1, I am able to ping 192.138.4.3 but not 192.138.4.2.

Following is the output of route -n command in Linux1

```
Linux1# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.135.18.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
0.0.0.0         10.135.18.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

In Linux 2:

```
Linux2# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.138.14.0    192.138.14.4    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth4
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth4
192.138.4.0     192.138.4.3     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.135.18.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.138.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2 
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 eth4
0.0.0.0         10.135.18.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

In Linux 3:

```
Linux3# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.135.18.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth3
0.0.0.0         10.135.18.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I have enabled IP forwarding in Linux 2

```
Linux2# vi /etc/sysctl.conf
# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Linux2#: sysctl -p 
sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.sysrq = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

The result of iptables -L in Linux 2:

```
Linux2# iptables -L  
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

To ping Linux3 from Linux 1, should I be adding specific rules for icmp in iptables ? If not, What am I missing ?

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314404/ping-fails-between-two-linux-systems-via-an-intermediate-linux> answers the question

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your setup.

First, you are using public, routable addresses as if they were private addresses. For instance, 192.138.14.1 is  Chapters Capital Management, LLC in NJ, while 192.138.4.1 is the University of London's (UK) Computing Center. And so on. Please go back to using addresses in the range 192.168.0.0/16.

Second, your routing tables contain many errors. You'd better start over, erasing completely current routing tables, and configuring them as follows via the current utility **ip** from the **iprouter2** package instead of obsolete utilities like *route*.

On Linux1, let the network manager or dhcp negotiate the local routing table, then add:

```
  ip route add default via 192.168.14.4
```

Same on Linux3, except that the command is:

```
  ip route add default via 192.168.4.3
```

Same on Linux2, except:

```
  ip route add default via 10.135.18.1
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This way Linux2 acts as the router/gateway for both Linux1 and Linux3, it has a suitable Internet-facing gateway itself, and cloaks Internet-bound traffic from Linux1 and Linux3 as if it were its own (this is the meaning of the `iptables` command).

Please notice that in the above I already converted addresses in the 192.138.0.0/16 range to the 192.168.0.0/16 range.

Answer (score -1):

Both you linux1 and linux3 servers have 192.138.4.0 and 192.168.14.0 routed locally. So nothing is sent to linux2 for routing

Linux 1

```
Linux1# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1 
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Linux3

```
Linux3# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.138.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
192.138.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
```

Can you give the result of those command on linux1 and linux3 ?

```
# ip -4 addr list
# ip route list
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it may be a comment.You should please refrain from posting as answers your comments, until you have earned the privilege to post comments. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add comment to the main question.

Comment: There is an answer : the routes are incorrect because it lake gateway (that should be linux2)